# Facebook login to site "An error occurred. Please try again later." happens only sometimes

Tags: facebook, authentication

The website has moved from one domain name and server to another domain name and server. Facebook login doesn't work when I press fb login on the page, it says standard **An error occurred. Please try again later.**.

I had such kind of problem earlier because App ID: or App Secret: were incorrect. Now that's not a problem, they are correct (doublechecked).

```
The settings in the fb account to be able to login from <mydomain>.com via fb are:
Display Name:  Some name
Namespace:  <I left it empty>
Contact Email:  support@<mydomain>.com
App Domains:   www.<mydomain>.com

Hosting URL: You have not generated a URL through one of our partners (Get one)
Sandbox Mode: Disabled

Website with Facebook Login:
Site URL:  http://www.<mydomain>.com
```

That's it. It doesn't work (if you were NOT logged in into fb account from the browser you're trying to use to login to my web site via fb)

I've just switched to sandbox enabled and sandbox disabled back (probably, some settings need to be refreshed, I don't know).

It still doesn't work.

Tested on several browsers.

Moreover, once I logged in into FB using my account and then signed out, it looks like it goes to the facebook page and suggests to login, everything looks fine. And it works even if I cleaned the cache and cookies in Chrome (the magic), once I logged in into fb.
Does anyone know what is the problem and how to fix it?

And of course, I used the real domain name instead of .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution found! Let me answer my question. In my case in the field **App Domains:** both `www.<mydomain>.com` and `<mydomain>.com` should be typed.

Answer (score 0):

1. Do you have "Website with Facebook Login" configured in your facebook app settings?
2. Are the domain/app_id in the url of facebook login popup correct?

If that doesn't solve your problem, share your login code here.

Comment: I've just found the solution. Please see my answer to my question what was the problem. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

i also had this problem once.in chrome you have to disable one plugin => facebook disconnect

and i got every thin working fine.